# How to store result in list in async method?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have the following method that generates data for me:

```
async def fetch_url(self, video_id):
    data = await self.s3.generate_presigned_url(...video_id...)
    return data

def convert_to_json(self, data):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []
    urls = [row[0] for row in data]
    for url in urls:
        tasks.append(fetch_url(url))
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    loop.close()
```

How to store result from `fetch_url` in some list?

Comment: Check the return value of `run_until_complete`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

> … If all the tasks are done successfully, the returned future’s result is the list of results (in the order of the original sequence, not necessarily the order of results arrival). …

That is, if you `await` the gathered result, you will get a list of fetched `data`

[`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete):

> Return the Future’s result, or raise its exception.

That is `run_until_complete` will return the result `gather`, which is the list of fetched `data`.

The stored result is simply:

```
...
all_data = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
return all_data
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After I run this code I got `TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression` inside fetch_url. How can I fix that?

Comment: @ipetr This means `fetch` is not really an async method. You need to use an async request library like [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#aiohttp-client) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio.

Comment: I use aiohttp. `fetch` is return `await self.s3.generate_presigned_url(...video_id...)`. Update my question

Comment: @ipetr well `generate_presigned_url` is not async either.