# Is there any advantage to wrapping a sequential library with asyncio and using an event loop over regular multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await

[Wrapping synchronous requests into asyncio (async/await)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745642/wrapping-synchronous-requests-into-asyncio-async-await)

In the top answer here, they wrap boto3 with asyncio. But from the way they describe it, they are just using asyncio to drop the task into the asyncio event loop, which by default is a threadpool. I dont really understand how this is an advantage from a regular threadpool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no gain in it, except that it is easier to call the wrapped functions from other asyncio code.

But if, at each use of the synchronous library you do call `loop.run_in_executor`  you have essentially the same effect.

However keep in mind that *readability counts*: if byusing a short wrapper one is able to shave a big expression, or even 2-3 lines in several places, and have all code written  "linearly" as is the "grail" of asyncio code, that is no little gain.

In terms of performance, there is simply no difference.