# Rewrite a library with blocking requests into async ones

Tags: python, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio

There is a library that uses blocking `requests` in its core and I would like to rewrite it into asynchronous version, so could you please advise  what would be the best/easiest strategy to do so.

The whole library, after several nested functions, calls one function:

```
def _send_http_request(self, url, payload, method='post', **kwargs):
# type: (Text, Optional[Text], Text, dict) -> Response

response = request(method=method, url=url, data=payload, **kwargs)

return response
```

Just putting `async` in front of it wont work since it is deeply nested in blocking functions. And rewriting everything would be a way too much hassle.
I had a look into `aiohttp`, `trio`, `asks` and kinda got lost, which one is better. I know about `celery` or `dask`, but I need async.

Comment: what do you mean you need async? You need to fire a function call asynchronously and provide some sort of callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Rewrite `_send_http_request` to be async (using, for example, [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#client-quickstart)) and further rewrite all functions that use `_send_http_request` to be async either. Yes, it's much work to do, but this is how `asyncio` fundamentally designed.
2. Wrap only top-level blocking functions (functions with I/O) you need to run asynchronously with [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio). If you aren't going to make millions of requests you won't see much performance difference with option above since main bottleneck is still I/O. Otherwise threads overhead will be noticeable compared to pure `asyncio` solution.
3. Try other solution instead of `asyncio`. For example, [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#introduction) and its [monkey-patching](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching). This approach has own pros and cons.