# Make method of derived class async

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have to create and use a class derived from an upstream package (not modifiable)
I want/need to add/modify a method in the derived class that should be async because i need to await a websocket send/recv in the method
I tried just to add async to the method but i get the message (from the base class method) that my method from derived class `RuntimeWarning: coroutine MyCopyProgressHandler.end was never awaited`
Is there a way to "convert" derived class method to async?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to convert sync method to async you have [several different options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55130187/1113207). Second one (`run_in_executor`) is probably the easiest one.

For example, this is how you can make sync function `requests.get` to run asynchronously:

```
import asyncio
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)


async def get(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    response = await loop.run_in_executor(
        executor, 
        requests.get, 
        url
    )
    return response.text


async def main():
    res = await get('http://httpbin.org/get')
    print(res)


asyncio.run(main())
```