# How to run a function asynchronously as “fire and forget”?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-asyncio

I have a Python Kafka consumer application where I consume the messages and then call an external webservice synchronously. The webservice takes a minute to process the message and send the response.

Is there a way to consume the message, send the request to the Web service and consume the next message without waiting for the response?

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'spring_test',
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='my-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')));
```

This is how I wait for the messages and send an external Web request

```
def consume_msgs():
 for message in consumer:
    message = message.value;
    send('{}'.format(message))

consume_msgs()
```

The function `send()` takes one minute before I get the response. I want to start consuming the next message in the meantime asynchronously but I don't know where to start

```
def send(pload) :
 import requests
 r = requests.post('someurl',data = pload)
 print(r)
```

Comment: Could you share your send function?

Comment: Sure. Just edited the question

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer yet, since i can't recall if there are any major differences between how the python consumer handles batching vs the java consumer but I believe if you make async network calls on a batch of message using something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio, you can await the completion of a batch and then call `commit` afterwards.

Comment: Actually looks like the people who made AIO also have an async kafka consumer https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but could you just spin each call to `send` out into a thread? Something like this the below. This way the for loop will continue without waiting for `send` to return. You may have to throttle the number of threads somehow if you are consuming data far quicker than you are processing it.

```
from threading import Thread  


def consume_msgs():
 for message in consumer:
    message = message.value;
    Thread(target=send, args = ('{}'.format(message),)).start()

consume_msgs()
```